# Connect Trial Version of Ubuntu Mate to Network

Tags: networking, mate

I have plugged into my HP laptop a flashdrive with the trial version of Ubuntu Mate on it.  Upon running the trial version, the network icon in the top bar is black.  When I right click on it, no wireless networks are shown, just a statement of "Enable Network" preceeded by a check mark.

1. How to I activate network connections (or just connect to my home network)
2. Is that that the trial version doesn't interact with networks? (this version of Mate was installed on another laptop, and the network connects just fine on the installed version)
   Thanks for any advise you can provide

Comment: What you are seeing is the driver for your network device is not in the default kernel. You did not say wired or wireless. If it was, yes you would be able to access the Internet and the Intranet. The other machine must have a different network card.

Comment: "*Is that that the trial version doesn't interact with networks?*" No, the "Try Ubuntu" version works exactly like an installed version, and is helpful for troubleshooting hardware issues (which is what you actually have). See [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Does your laptop have a physical switch to deactivate the wireless network? Some do have such switch :) If there is no such switch, it is likely a missing driver issue like @David said.